# Error a la hora de comparar contraseñas con bcrypt.checkpw()

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite3, hash

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con Python en el framework Django, estoy intentado comparar una contraseña que viene de un formulario de login con otra contraseña hasheada guardada en una base de datos sqlite3.

Me sale el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis archivos de configuración son los siguientes:

Función de login (en la que entiendo que reside el error):
**`views.py`**

```
def FormLogin(request):
\#Si el metodo detectado es POST almacenamos el formularioLogin en la varibles form
if request.method == 'POST':
form = FormularioLogin(request.POST)
\#Si los datos del formulario son válidos se ejecturará la siguiente acción
if form.is_valid():
usuarioLogin = form.cleaned_data\['Usuario'\]
contraseñaLogin = form.cleaned_data\['Password'\]
c_usuario = Usuarios.objects.filter(Usuario__iexact=usuarioLogin).values('Password').first()
pass_cusuario = c_usuario\["Password"\]
result = bcrypt.checkpw(pass_cusuariocontraseñaLogin.encode('utf8'))


> Este if es por poner algo, no le hagáis mucho caso

                        if result: 
                                HttpResponse("SI")
                        else:
                                HttpResponse("NO")
    
        else:
            form = FormularioLogin()
            #Cargamos la instancia del formulario en la template de "web/login.html" 
        return render(request, "web/login.html", {'form':form})
```

Función de registro de usuario (Añado esta función también por si clarifica alguna duda):

```
def FormRegistro(request):
\#Si el metodo detectado es POST almacenamos el formularioLogin en la varibles form
if request.method == 'POST':
form = FormularioRegistro(request.POST)
\#Si los datos del formulario son válidos se ejecturará la siguiente acción
if form.is_valid():
try:  
\#Mediante el módulo try execpt probamos que los datos sacados del formulario
\#Se puedan insertar dentro de la base de datos de usuarios

                                NombreUsuario = form.cleaned_data['Nombre']
                                ApellidoUsuario = form.cleaned_data['Apellido']
                                UsuarioUsuario = form.cleaned_data['Usuario']
                                PasswdUsuario = form.cleaned_data['Contraseña']
                                #Mediante el módulo bcrypt hasheamos la contraseña.
                                hashed_value = bcrypt.hashpw(PasswdUsuario.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
                                #Con Usuarios.objects.create() añadimos los datos dentro de la tabla de usuarios.
                                crearuser = Usuarios.objects.create(Nombre=NombreUsuario, 
                                Apellidos=ApellidoUsuario, Usuario=UsuarioUsuario, Password=hashed_value)
                                #Guardamos los datos en la tabla
                                crearuser.save()
                        except IntegrityError:
                                #Si falla algun campo devolverá la variable "err" con el valor true
                                return render(request, "web/signup.html", {'err':True, 'form':form})
    
                        else:
                                #Si no falla nos devolverá a la página de inicio
                                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("miapp:index"))
        else:
            form = FormularioRegistro()
            #Cargamos la instancia del formulario en la template de "web/signup.html" 
        return render(request, "web/signup.html", {'form':form})
```

Aquí os dejo mi archivo models.py

**`models.py`**:

```
    
    from django.db import models
    # Create your models here.
    
    class Usuarios(models.Model):
        Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        Usuario = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
        Password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comparación de contraseñas, he intentado a cambiar el orden de los argumentos en la función de `bcrypt.checkpw()` y nada, también he codificado la contraseña a comparar.

Comment: Aquí: `bcrypt.checkpw(pass_cusuariocontraseñaLogin.encode('utf8'))` parece que te falta una coma (`,`). Tal vez debe ser: `bcrypt.checkpw(pass_cusuario, contraseñaLogin.encode('utf8'))`. Por otro lado, evita usar caracteres como `ñ` para el nombre de variables. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras buenas, ya he puesto la coma y ni con esas, aprovechando el error de la coma también he vuelto a cambiar el orden de los argumentos de >bcrypt.checkpw() y sobre lo de las >ñ lo tendré en cuenta para futuras ocasiones.